# What are the issues plaguing my lemon tree and how can I bring it back to glory?

Tags: diseases, insects, citrus, lemons

Have just moved house and have a lemon tree that appears to be suffering from numerous issues. What exactly is causing the issues seen in the below pictures, and how can I effectively treat them?

I've seen ants, spiders and other insects on the tree (but would like to understand more). I've been spraying it with organic pyrethrum and have fed the tree with citrus fertiliser. Ideally I'd like to have it productive within a year!

Location: temperate Australia; semi-shaded.

[image][image]
[image][image]

Comment: I see flowers, new leaves, and good colour on both old and new leaves. Maybe cut the other tree overshading the lemon.